# error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type] } ^

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, return-value, definition

The problem is basically about to generate a arithmetic expression from a given 'n' numbers , and the expression should be divisible by 101. we can only have  +,-,* operators and expression is left associative.

I have tried all the available solution on , that are already mentioned on stack overflow, like closing the expressions with else and many more

```
bool calci(int a[],int n,int sum,int pos,char operato[],deque<int>&q,deque<char>&qc)
{

    if(sum%101==0)
    {   //cout<<"sum:"<<sum<<endl;
        return true;
    }

    else if(pos==n)
        {return false;}
    else
    {
    for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
    {  // cout<<"here for "<<a[pos]<<endl;
        sum=addto(sum,a[pos],operato[k]);
        qc.push_back(operato[k]);
        q.push_back(a[pos]);
        bool kyaagesemila=calci(a,n,sum,pos+1,operato,q,qc);
        if(kyaagesemila)
            {
                return true;
            }
        sum=removefrom(sum,a[pos],operato[k]);
        qc.pop_back();
        q.pop_back();
    }
    }
}
```

i am getting a compilation error

````
solution.cc:53:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
 ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is clear enough. The function has the return type `bool` but returns nothing in some execution paths.

Where is there in the last else statement a return statement with a boolean expression?

Or you need to rewrite the last else statement such a way that it would return a boolean expression outside the loop.

For example after the loop you can add statement

```
return false;
```

P.S. Use English words as variable identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly what it says: your code doesn't always return (or, if it does, that's due to logic that the compiler doesn't have the capability or desire to work out).

If control enters the loop in the `else`, and no iteration has `kyaagesemila == true`, it will simply never reach a `return` statement.

Put a `return false;` or a `return true;` at the end of the `else`, according to your desired logic.